# In Emacs, how to line up equals signs in a series of initialization statements?

Tags: emacs, formatting, code-formatting

I saw this somewhere, but cannot find it now. 
Is there a built-in function in emacs, or does someone have elisp, to line up all the equals signs in a series of inititialization statments in cc-mode?

Before:

```
int t=9;
Graphics g = new Graphics();
List<String> list = new List<String>();
```

After:

```
int          t    = 9;
Graphics     g    = new Graphics();
List<String> list = new List<String>();
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `M-x align-regexp` (here, `M-x align-regexp RET = RET`). You can also add an "alignment rule" to the variable `align-rules-list`, so that in future `M-x align` will do it. See the documentation (`C-h f align`) for details.

Comment: Ok, I've bound this to C-x |.   How did I use emacs for so long and not know about this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: The only problem with this is that it "tabifies" the output, which is probably not what you want.  Do you know any way to prevent this?

Comment: harpo: I've added a new answer for your question.

Comment: This URL helped with making this into a fn: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633120/emacs-hotkey-to-align-equal-signs

Answer (score 18):

This is in response to harpo's comment to ShreevatsaR's answer:

> The only problem with this is that it "tabifies" the output, which is probably not what you want. Do you know any way to prevent this?

Here's what I did to resolve that issue:

```
;; Align with spaces only
(defadvice align-regexp (around align-regexp-with-spaces)
  "Never use tabs for alignment."
  (let ((indent-tabs-mode nil))
    ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'align-regexp)
```

Comment: This is not a great answer to the original question, but valuable, valuable, valuable.  (I think I just Ballmered.)

Comment: It took me some time to understand what this [does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921225/what-does-ad-activate-do)...

Answer (score 7):

M-x align should do the trick.