# Emacs hotkey to align equal signs

Tags: emacs

I'd like to put something like this in my .emacs:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-c a =") 
  (lambda () (interactive) 
    (align-regexp (region-beginning) (region-end) "=")))
```

But whenever I run it, I get an error "Wrong type argument: numberp, nil".

What does this error mean and how do I get the effect I'm looking for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you are my dear fellow.

```
(defun align-to-equals (begin end)
  "Align region to equal signs"
   (interactive "r")
   (align-regexp begin end "\\(\\s-*\\)=" 1 1 ))
```

The `(\s-*)` prefix is used internally by align-regexp

From the `align.el`

```
(list (concat "\\(\\s-*\\)"
```

John Wiegley just neglected to document it, and I guess most people just use align-regexp interactively, or just record and save a macro!

Comment: I'll stil give you a +1 though :) ... that \s-* prefix is very odd.

Comment: As usual, I beg you all to use "rx" so that those who read your code will not go crazy or blind:

    (rx (group (zero-or-more (syntax whitespace))) "=")

is exactly equivalent to 

    "\\(\\s-*\\)="

Comment: @offby1, that's weird.  I can grok \(\\s-*\), but that rx group... zero-or-more etc etc stuff.... I have no idea what that is.  I guess I am already one of the "touched" ones.

Comment: @slomojo - good answer but you left one thing out of the explanation - why do we need to specify numbers for GROUP and SPACING? They are documented as optional. The real reason for the error reported by OP ( "Wrong type argument: numberp, nil") is that he did not specify GROUP and SPACING.  You specified 1 and 1 for those, thus avoiding the error. Seems like these "optional" args are NOT actually optional.

Comment: @Cheeso, Yes, it was implied by the use of arbitrary values, and you're quite right ... they are not optional, it's a case of bad documentation in the `align.el` library.

Comment: @slomojo, anyway, thanks very much for the tip.  This helped me, too.

Comment: Btw, it would be pretty cool if you didn't put caps in your answers, unless you actually intend to convey that you are SHOUTING. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 2):

"thunk" from #emacs solved it:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-c a =") 
  (lambda () (interactive) 
    (align-regexp (region-beginning) (region-end) "\\(\\s-*\\)=" 1 1 nil)))
```

Someone care to explain the strange prefix to the "="?

Comment: Note that the last nil is optional, and the 1 1 are not. The documentation for align.el needs a tidy up.

Answer (score 0):

I picked apart the source of `align-regexp` (install `emacs23-el` on debian) and came up with this:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-c a =") 
  (lambda () (interactive) 
    (align-region (region-beginning)
                  (region-end)
                  'entire
                  (list (list nil
                              (cons 'regexp "\\(\\s-*\\)=")
                              (cons 'group 1)
                              (cons 'bogus nil)
                              (cons 'spacing 1)))
                  nil
                  nil)))
```

Comment: But surely it is possible to do this assignment without digging out the innards of the align command?

Comment: I would've thought so, but I don't understand `align.el` all that well.