# How can I add intelligent alignment of assignments and hashes to indent-region in emacs?

Tags: ruby, emacs, elisp, code-formatting

When I have the code:

```
a = 1
foo = 2
```

and I want to make it look like:

```
a   = 1
foo = 2
```

I can use the align-to-equals function defined here:

[Emacs hotkey to align equal signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633120/emacs-hotkey-to-align-equal-signs)

by selecting the area and running the function. I can alter the function to work for hashes as well by changing the '=' in the function definition to '=>' and have:

```
bar = { :a => 1,
 :foo => 2 }
```

be converted to:

```
bar = { :a   => 1,
        :foo => 2 }
```

I want this alignment to be done to all of my code when I select the whole buffer and run indent-region. But I want it to be done intelligently - not aligning every single '=' in the buffer to the rightmost '=', but instead doing it for assignment blocks and individual hash literals.

**EDIT:** To clarify this last part, say I have the following buffer:

```
a = 1
foo = 2

some_other_code

def fn
  bar = { :a => 1,
   :foo => 2 }
end
```

I want to do 'C-x h' (select whole buffer), 'M-C-\' (indent-region) and have it look like this:

```
a   = 1
foo = 2

some_other_code

def fn
  bar = { :a   => 1,
          :foo => 2 }
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `M-x align-regexp` `=`. And same for others as well.

Comment: This works as a replacement to the align-to-equals function, but how can I add this to indent-region and have it only applied locally to hash definitions or groups of assignments? (See edit to original question for clarification of what I mean by this.)

Comment: Perhaps with a new defun that would call to indent-region followed by align-regexp.  But I would simply do indent-region followed by all the align-regexp manually.  I am not sure if this workflow has enough appeal for such automation.

Answer (score 1):

align.el give the align function for this:

in .emacs add

```
     (push (ruby-hash-string
             (regexp . "\\(\\s-*\\)\\(\"[^\"]*\"\\|:[a-zA-Z]*\\)\\(\\s-*\\)=>\\(\\s-*\\)")
             (group . (1 3 4))
             (repeat . t)
             (modes '(ruby-mode)))
        align-rules-list)
```

then M-x align will align hashes in ruby-mode. You need to add other group for other thuings you want to align.

Comment: Fails with Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function ruby-hash-string) for me